# asp.net log files permissions

Tags: asp.net

Our asp.net app writes errors to a text log file in the web sites root folder. This has lead to all sorts of permission problems, different flavors of IIS and windows allow different things by default.

So what I am wondering is there a location somewhere in Windows where all types of users can write a file without any extra permissions that will also work for all IIS and flavors of windows?

I am thinking of the ApplicationData folder, but did this exist in Server 2003 ?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Do you want to stick with files? You can utilize Windows' Event Log, or your site's SQL database (if any) for logging.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use the `App_Data` subfolder of your web application for this. By default it's not viewable from the web, so Internet clients won't be able to read the logs.

Depending on your deployment method, you might have to change the permission to allow write access to this folder (to the user under which your web application is running).

---

Alternatively, there is a place where every user can write to: It's that user's temporary folder, which you can access through [Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx). This, however, does not sound like a suitable location for log files.

Answer (score 0):

You should always first think about wwwroot folder (%systemdrive%\inetpub\wwwroot) because it has the required permission.

The permission you need is to set a full control for IIS_IUSRS

Edit: you can simply give Everyone Full Control (**not recommended at all**) but this solves most of ntfs permissions issues with IIS